# In Sitecore 7.0 how to apply rules for resolving bucket folder path?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I installed a fresh Sitecore 7.0 instance on my local. I created an Item bucket. I thought of creating folder structure on the basis on name like pages starting with alphabet should go in a folder named A as the page names are not supposed to change. I found many articles where I found that there are 3 default  rules: CreateDateBasedPath, CreateIDBasedPath and CreateItemNameBasedPath. I have following two questions:-

1. In my Sitecore instance I opened the /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Item Buckets Settings item. I can't see "Rules for Resolving bucket folder path". Am I supposed change any configuration for this or sitecore 7.0 does not support applying rules?
2. My assumption is CreateItemNameBasedPath will create folder structure as A/Apage and B/Bpage. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore 7 does not allow using the Rules Engine for bucket folders. That was new in Sitecore 8.

To change the bucket path you will need to implement a custom `BucketFolderPathResolver`.  There is a good post on how to do that here: http://www.brimit.com/blog/custom-bucket-structure

Comment: article explains custom implementation for 7.2, because in sitecore 7.0 we don't have name as parameter.
above solution will not work for sitecore 7.0